# Ansible regex_search/regex_findall

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm trying to parse the output of a command that returned a line like this (there's more output, but this is the line that I'm after):

> Remaining Time: 3 Minutes and 12 Seconds

And when there is no time left it returns a line like this:

> Remaining Time: 0 Seconds

I'd like to extract the amount of minutes and seconds, so I can feed it to GNU date -d. First I tried this:

```
- name: determine how much time we have left
    set_fact:
      time_left: "{{ cmd_output.stdout | regex_search(time_left_regex, '\\1', '\\2') | join(' ') }}"
    vars:
      time_left_regex: 'Remaining Time: ([0-9]+ Minutes) and ([0-9]+ Seconds)'
```

But this does not handle the case when there is no time left. So I then tried something like this:

```
- name: determine how much time we have left
    set_fact:
      time_left: "{{ cmd_output.stdout | regex_findall(time_left_regex, '\\1') }}"
    vars:
      time_left_regex: 'Next Execution:.*([0-9]{1,2} (Minutes|Seconds))'
```

But this only returns something like:

> ok: [localhost] => {
>       "msg": "time left: [[u'2 Seconds', u'Seconds']]" }

I think I'm on the right track but I need a better regex, so maybe somebody can help me out here?
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `Remaining Time: (?:([0-9]+ Minutes) and )?([0-9]+ Seconds)` See https://regex101.com/r/JblAAg/1

Answer (score 0):

You can make the minutes part optional. The minutes will be in group 1 and the seconds will be in group 2.

```
Remaining Time: (?:([0-9]+ Minutes) and )?([0-9]+ Seconds)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JblAAg/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the regex, it works perfect. However, I have trouble incorporating it in my ansible playbook. If I use it with regex_search and the two backreferences, it returns 'None' when the first one is empty (in the case when no time is left).

I'll also take a look at  Vladimirs aproach, which boggles my mind for now :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to split the string (line) and combine a dictionary. For example

```
    - set_fact:
        time_left: "{{ time_left|default({})|
                       combine({myline[item]: myline[item+1]}) }}"
      loop: "{{ range(0, myline|length + 1, 3)|list }}"
      vars:
        myline: "{{ cmd_output.stdout.split(':').1.split()|reverse|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: time_left
```

for various command outputs

```
cmd_output.stdout: 'Remaining Time: 3 Minutes and 12 Seconds'
cmd_output.stdout: 'Remaining Time: 0 Seconds'
cmd_output.stdout: 'Remaining Time: 2 Days and 7 Hours and 3 Minutes and 12 Seconds'
```

gives (respectively)

```
    "time_left": {
        "Minutes": "3", 
        "Seconds": "12"
    }
```

```
    "time_left": {
        "Seconds": "0"
    }
```

```
    "time_left": {
        "Days": "2", 
        "Hours": "7", 
        "Minutes": "3", 
        "Seconds": "12"
    }
```