# ansible join list

Tags: regex, list, join, ansible

I run into a problem joining a list in ansible. Please look at the following playbook excerpt:

```
    - name: determine how much time we have left
      set_fact:
        time_left1: "{{ cmd_output.stdout | regex_search(time_left_regex1, '\\1', '\\2') }}"
        time_left2: "{{ cmd_output.stdout | regex_findall(time_left_regex2, '\\1') }}"
      vars:
        time_left_regex1: 'Remaining Time: ([0-9]+ Minutes) and ([0-9]+ Seconds)'
        time_left_regex2: 'Remaining Time: (?:([0-9]+ Minutes) and )?([0-9]+ Seconds)'

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ time_left1 }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ time_left1 | join(' ') }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ time_left2 }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ time_left2 | join(' ') }}"
```

When I run this playbook I get:

> ok: [localhost] => {
>       "msg": [
>           "11 Minutes", 
>           "48 Seconds"
>       ] }
>
> ok: [localhost] => {
>       "msg": "11 Minutes 48 Seconds" }
>
> ok: [localhost] => {
>       "msg": [
>           [
>               "11 Minutes", 
>               "48 Seconds"
>           ]
>       ] }
>
> ok: [localhost] => {
>       "msg": [
>           "11 Minutes", 
>           "48 Seconds"
>       ] }

To me it seems that the **regex_search** returned I list that I can join to a simple string, and that **regex_findall** creates a nested list. Is this correct? And if so, how can convert the output to a string similar to the way **regex_search** works?

PS: for more information about the contents of **cmd_output** please take a look at my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60785464/ansible-regex-search-regex-findall)

Answer (score 2):

[flatten](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#list-filters) the nested list. For example

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ time_left2|flatten|join(' ') }}"
```